# how to clean the remains of a failed migration exchange (powershell)

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server, powershell-2.0, exchange-server-2010

I have a failed migration, I removed the migration batch, also removed the users of the migration batch, but every time I type

```
Get-SyncRequest - Identity info@mydomain.com
```

I keep seeing the failed migration. How do I clean this since powershell?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is default mailbox folders must be restored to the original state before you start the MAILBOX migration. So run the following steps in your windows workstation, where the mailbox profile resides. Run the migration after the command executed successfully

1. Close Outlook
2. Run outlook.exe /resetfolders

Thanks,
Manu